# how to show previous month number in my blog page

Tags: wordpress

I am beginner in wordpress and a little problem in blog post.

My problem is how to show a previous month number in my blog page, i show to you how is my blog page looking:

Spouse

This is my blog page title (just below of title)

Posted 2 month ago

---

So my question is how to create function for (posted **2** month ago).

Is this write way: `<?php the_time('j') ?>`

for previous month show in Numeric.

Please anybody help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple PHP issue of how you are asking to return the first date()

```
date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));
```

is returning Dec, and WP_Query needs the month number. First, try changing 'M' to 'm'.

```
date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));
```

If that doesn't work, try using the [date_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) and pass the year in as well.